# Turn get_posts as string into an array for use in theme admin options

Tags: functions, themes, get-posts, theme-options, array

I am trying to add a drop down list of all posts into a theme admin section...without forklifting the theme code.

I need to pass the post title and id into the 'options'=>array() like so:

```
'getting-started-link-id'=>array(
    'title'=>'LINK GETTING STARTED TO:',
    'name'=>'page-option-item-getting-started-link-id',
    'options'=>array('54'=>'Post #1','23'=>'Post #2', '654'=>'Post #3',)
    'type'=>'combobox'
),
```

I wrote a function that takes all the posts ID and name and turns them into a string:

```
function post_page_options(){
    $post_page_options = get_posts('category=orderby=title&order=asc&numberposts=');
    foreach( $post_page_options as $value ) :
        $str .= "'$value->ID'" . "=>'" . $value->post_title . "', ";
    endforeach; 
    return $str;
}
```

`$str` returns this:
        '54'=>'Post #1','23'=>'Post #2', '654'=>'Post #3',

I tried this but it does not work:

```
    'options'=>array( post_page_options() )
```

I tried turning the $str into an array() but the the array does not come out looking like the the format as in $str.

Somehow adding the results of the $str into the 'options'=> seems like the easist approach so the theme admin code will do what it is already written to do which is take the 'options'=> array and turn it into a drop down list.

Comment: My initial thought is that you look into `serialize` and `unserialize` as that is how arrays must be stored/retrieved in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
array('54'=>'Post #1','23'=>'Post #2', '654'=>'Post #3',)
```

... is ***not*** a string. It is an array definition.

All you need to do is create an array, which is what you want, and skip the string completely.

```
function post_page_options(){
    $post_page_options = get_posts('category=orderby=title&order=asc&numberposts=');
    foreach( $post_page_options as $value ) :
        $str[$value->ID] = $value->post_title;
    endforeach; 
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: That was spot on and worked. I tried that first but could not get the arraignment right. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well one slight problem...I get this: <option rel="Module 1 - Getting Started">Module 1 - Getting Started</option> and I need <option rel="34">Module 1 - Getting Started</option> where rel="34" is the post id.

Comment: The code that _uses_ the array is using the value for both. To use an array like you want it needs to be using the key for one and the value for another.